# 401 on analytics fetch using google analytics API in VB.net (Invalid Credentials)

Tags: .net, vb.net, oauth-2.0

I'm rewriting a windows service that fetches data from the google analytics API as our current version runs on v2.3 and we want to move up to v3.

I've downloaded the google api .net libraries and have the following code to authorise and fetch data from google. I know that the query is ok as it runs in the query explorer.

When I run it from my server, I get a 401 error with invalid credentials and am not sure how to fix it. I'm using the following code.

```
    Dim auth As New OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, User, DomainName)

    Dim ga As New AnalyticsService(auth)
    ga.Key = ApiKey ' Simple API Access - API Key 

    Dim query = ga.Data.Ga.Get("ga:" + myprofileID, _startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), _endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "ga:totalEvents")
    query.Dimensions = "ga:eventLabel,ga:source,ga:medium,ga:keyword,ga:campaign,ga:isMobile,ga:date"

    Dim res = query.Fetch
```

The fetch returns the 401, not really sure what it's doing, there doesn't seem to be a way to set the scope using the Oauth2leggedauthentication class which may be an issue.

Also I'm using the client Id and secret for web Applications, I've set one up for installed applications as well but can't get either to work.

Neither the Oauth2LeggedAuthenticator or AnalyticsService expose the Oauth token so I'm wondering if that is part of the issue, but not sure how to get round the issue either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was unable to solve this without reverting to using ClientLogin to get authentication

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps

It's deprecated but hopefully there will be a more elegant OAuth solution before 2015 when the deprecation policy ends